# generate very different colors [R] from unique categories

Tags: r, colors, data.table, viridis

Currently I have a data.table with a column named `brand`, where `brand` is a character column.
I am using the following code to generate a color for each brand:

```
Library(viridis)

color.list <- df[, .(
  brand = sort(unique(brand)),
  brand.color = viridis::plasma(length(sort(unique(brand))))
)]
```

However when the data gets plotted some `brands` have different colors (ex. brand1 and brand2 have colors #DE6064FF and #E06363FF, respectively). However in practice these 2 colors don't differ too much (ex. both of them look like orange). How can I make the colors more different between them o they don't look the same

Comment: Question seems to be related to color palette produced by `viridis::plasma`, and not really to data.table. If colors are actually not exactly the same but they are being plotted as the same, then it could be a data.table problem but for that you should include plotting call as well.

Comment: Have you considered how many different brands you have? I just checked and the smallest n that produces those colors together is 93. `lapply(1:100, function(x){"#DE6064FF" %in% viridis::plasma(x) & "#E06363FF" %in% viridis::plasma(x)})`